# many divs using the same animation trying to include them in one line

Tags: jquery

I have multiple animations doing the same thing is there a way I can just include them in one heap.

```
           $('.info_box_title').animate({opacity: 1},'500');
           $('.info_box_status').animate({opacity: 1},'500');
           $('.info_box_about').animate({opacity: 1},'500');
```

something like

```
$('.info_box_title','.info_box_status','.info_box_about').animate({opacity: 1},'500');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are so close! Just put the selectors (comma-separated) all inside the two quotes:

`$('.info_box_title, .info_box_status, .info_box_about').animate({opacity: 1},'500');`

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: i guess no need to say samething again and again. This is my answer too.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer You guess and I believe.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this selector

```
$('.info_box_title, .info_box_status, .info_box_about')
```

or

```
$("div[class*=' info_box-']") // It selects all divs which contains 'info_box' text in their class name
```

or

```
$("div[class^='info_box-']") // It selects all divs whose class name starts with'info_box' text.
```

Comment: +1 simply because there are some good techniques given here for forming selectors

Comment: i guess no need to come back with a new idea and post it again and again when its already there. This would have been my edited answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function so you can use it on others if you need to:

```
function animateOpacity($item,$value,timing){
    $item.animate({opacity:$value},timing);
}

animateOpacity($('.info_box_title'),1,500);
animateOpacity($('.info_box_status'),1,500);
animateOpacity($('.info_box_about'),1,500);
```

This allows you to reuse it for a LOT of things ... even with different opacity and timing values. Or if you don't need it to be quite so extensible:

```
function animateOpacity($item){
    $item.animate({opacity:1},500);
}

animateOpacity($('.info_box_title'));
animateOpacity($('.info_box_status'));
animateOpacity($('.info_box_about'));
```